# Error when trim each string in an array

Tags: javascript

If I trim each string in an array,

`[' a ','  b','c  '].map(i=>i.trim())`

It works.

But `[' a ','  b','c  '].map(''.trim.call)` will cause `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

I thought it should work...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `bind` `call` to `String.prototyp.trim`

```
[' a ','  b','c  '].map(''.trim.call.bind(''.trim))

[' a ','  b','c  '].map(Function.prototype.call.bind(''.trim))
```

Right now you simply get `Function.prototype.call` and then invoke it with `undefined` context

```
const call = Function.prototyp.call

[' a ','  b','c  '].map(call)
```

So each step is just `call(item, index, array)` while `call` uses `this`

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! The explanation is very clear.